# Change color and style of a WPF Groupbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I change:

- 1st the color of the groupbox header?
- 2nd the height of the groupbox header?

For now, I have a simply groupbox with a text box inside it:

```
<GroupBox
   Width="429"
   Height="121"
   Margin="10,352,0,0"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   VerticalAlignment="Top"
   Header="Telegram Preview">
   <Grid>
      <TextBox
         Width="391"
         Height="55"
         Margin="10,10,0,0"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Text=""
         TextWrapping="Wrap" />

   </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

[image: Original group box style]

I tried in this way but the result is horrible:

```
<GroupBox
   Width="429"
   Height="114"
   Margin="0,226,0,0"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   VerticalAlignment="Top">
   <GroupBox.Header>
      <Border Background="Green">
         <TextBlock Text="header..." />
      </Border>
   </GroupBox.Header>
   <TextBlock Text="content..."></TextBlock>
</GroupBox>
```

[image: Group box style with header background]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What does a group box header make it _more similar_ to WinForms? What is the result that you expect? Furthermore, your style is not the default WPF style, where does it come from?

Comment: Ignore the last question, I only want to modify the color and height of the header

Comment: For that, it is still necessary to know the style, because that is what you will have to adapt.

Comment: And how can I find the used style?

Comment: Do you use _MahApps.Metro_ or any other library?

Comment: Yes, this it what I use, and also I have installed material design nuget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library you are using looks like *MahApps.Metro*. In this case you can use the attached property `HeaderBackground` to set the background of the group box.

```
<GroupBox Width="429"
          Height="121"
          Margin="10,352,0,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Header="Telegram Preview"
          controls:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderBackground="Green"/>
```

The corresponding `controls` namespace is this one:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```

In order to change the height of the `GroupBox`, you would have to adapt the default control style:

- Copy the resource dictionary for the [default `GroupBox` style from Gitub](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.GroupBox.xaml) to your project
- Add the resource dictionary after the other MahApps dictionaries in `App.xaml`
- Fix the XML namespaces in the copied resource dictionary

  ```
  xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/shared"
  xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
  ```
- Remove the `x:Key` from the group box style in the dictionary to make it an implicit style that is applied to all `GroupBox`es in the application or rename the key and use it later to reference the style explicitly
- Set an explicit height to the `Border` named `HeaderSite` or adapt it to your needs

As you can see, this is a cumbersome task. However, there is an easier *workaround* to this. You can create a header data template with a `TextBlock` or any other control depending on your `Header` content type and assign an explicit `Height` there.

```
<GroupBox Width="429"
          Height="121"
          Margin="10,352,0,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Header="Telegram Preview"
          Controls:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderBackground="Green">
   <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Height="50"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
</GroupBox>
```